# Why does Tony Montana hate Colombians?

Tags: character, scarface

In *Scarface* right after making the deal with Omar Suarez, Tony says he explicitly doesn't like Colombians but the reason is never shown in the movie. What is it?

Comment: Maybe a theory would be that his mother was raped by a Colombian but that falls apart because I don't know about his sister Gina his scars would be self-inflicted because he does not want to look like his father that he does not know

Comment: @AlucardMoon can you have the reference about the rape?

Answer (score 4):

> In the late 70s early 80s, the colombians cut off the cubans from the cocaine smuggling trade. Cuba was the "middle man" and when the colombians decided to keep all the profit, that's when the drug wars began.

I hope [this answer from Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110605140838AA4VP0H) will help you to understand Tony's hate for Colombians. Besides that Tony is considered that they are not good for business, probably referring to the brutal methods by which Colombian cartels are known.